# What exactly happens when a browser doesn't support media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm building my site with mediaqueries to adapt to different screen sizes.

By coincidence I checked my site in an old pc with an unupdated browser and found out that I was getting a mix of mobile content and desktop content. However I didn't have a way to see the code since there was no firebug or similar installed.

My question is what happens if the browser doens't accept media queries in css?

- Does it ignore everything inside the condition?
- Or does it run everything inside the condition whatever the condition is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the browser doesn't support Media Queries then nothing happens. It ignores the entire conditional block of styles.

If you wanted to support then you can use this JS http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: That adds support for media queries for any browser? That's good to know. Just a question it says "Doesn't work on @import'ed stylesheets". What does that mean? It doesn't work with external .css stylesheets?

Comment: May be he is talking about this http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/ . Use <link type="stylesheet"/> for this.