# What exactly happens when a browser doesn't support feature queries?

Tags: css, browser-feature-detection

Feature queries are useful for loading CSS conditionally. They let you provide a section of CSS code only to browsers that support a specified feature.

```
@supports (feature-name: feature-value) {
    /* Some CSS code here, for browsers that support feature-name: feature-value */
}
```

However, many older browsers don't have support for feature queries.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries

For browsers without feature query support, what will happen to the CSS inside a feature query? Will the browser load and use it? Or just skip or ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature queries, and everything in them, are ignored by browsers that don't support them.

```
@supports (feature-name: feature-value) {
    /*  CSS inside the feature query is visible 
        only to browsers that support feature queries.
        Invisible to other browsers, 
        even if they support feature-name: feature-value. */
}
```

For those browsers, you'll need to use other feature-detection tools such as [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

[CSS media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10748527/3345375) are similar. If a browser doesn't support media queries / feature queries, it just skips over them and everything inside.

Comment: With this behavior in mind, I wonder should I write `@supports` as well as including Modernizr detection to cover all ground? It'd be lots more code..

Comment: There’s some overlap. `@supports` in a CSS file is a simple way to test for CSS features. Modernizr is more comprehensive, and can also test for JavaScript features. If you’re using Modernizr, then using `@supports` might be redundant.